# Allow lambda function to access S3 bucket but block external IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to write in a S3 bucket with the help of a lambda function but would like to have the S3 bucket accessible only to IPs inside office network.

I have used this bucket policy but this does not allow my lambda to write to the S3 bucket, when i remove the IP blocking part, lambda function works fine.

How can i change this bucket policy so that it allows lambda to write but does not allow external IPS to access the S3 bucket?

Thanks!

```
{


"Version": "2012-10-17",

    "Id": "",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSESPuts",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ses.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket.net/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:Referer": "230513111850"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowECSPuts",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket.net/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::abc.net/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::abc.net"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": [
                        "AROAJIS5E4JXTWB4RTX3I:*",
                        "230513111751"
                    ]
                },
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                      "81.111.111.111/24" --dummy IP
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: `"81.111.111.111/24"` is IP address of your office which you would to deny, right ?

Comment: No, I want to allow only office IPs and block external IP addresses, the one in the code snippet above is just a dummy IP .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, it makes life easier if you can avoid `Deny` statements in policies.

Therefore, you could configure:

- An Amazon S3 bucket with a **Bucket Policy** that permits access from the desired CIDR range
- An **IAM Role for the Lambda function** that permits access to the Amazon S3 bucket

There should be no need for a `Deny` statement in the bucket policy since access is denied by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the problem is i want to deny access to all the IP address outside office network and IAM role in my case does have access to Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: Because S3 is private by default, there is no need to Deny something if it hasn't been Allowed in the first place. The difficulty with a Deny is that it always overrules an Allow, which makes it hard to make OR-type policies (eg allow SES _OR_ the Office IP range _OR_ Admins). For the Lambda function, you can simply grant it access to the S3 bucket via the IAM Role used by the Lambda function, rather than having to put it in the Bucket Policy.

Answer (score 0):

One typical approach is to place the lambda function inside a private VPC subnet. Then attach an S3 gateway VPC endpoint to it and set the corresponding S3 bucket policy to only allow certain actions performed from the VPC endpoint. [[ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html)]

Comment: I tried placing lambda in VPC also but it slows down the lambda and i am getting time out error after 900 sec.

Comment: You can change the timeout duration. But keep in mind that lambda function in a VPC will throw an error for the first run if you don't use it for a while. You should add a retry logic for the case.

Comment: Also, you need to increase the reversed concurrency count for the function. It's currently not supported for lambdas in VPC to use concurrency from the pool.

Comment: @grnc Thanks! But the lambda function is getting timed out after 15 mins and i have kept timeout duration max i.e 15 mins , cannot increase beyond that

Comment: Is the Lambda function hanging when it is trying to access S3 via the VPC Endpoint? If so, it is either caused by the policy on the VPC Endpoint, or the Route Table configuration (which should actually be automatic). Or, is the Lambda function attempting to access the Internet?